# Looking for a book or collection of specific type of puzzles

Tags: reference-request

This is a reference request: my apologies in advance if it's not entirely appropriate for this SE. I recently came across this little puzzle: There are 20 apples in a basket on the floor. Around the basket are 20 kids. How do you give each kid one apple such that at the end, one apple still remains in the basket?

This seems like a kind of puzzle that one won't be able to solve if one makes assumptions and is rigid in their thinking (e.g.

> one might be so focused on kids and apples that they ignore the basket as an active object that can be moved around

Another example: why are 1968 dollars worth more than 1964 dollars?

> Since one is so used to thinking of these as years, one doesn't even consider the possibility that these numbers may indicate the amount rather than the year

I admit I fell for the traps in both cases. So to any puzzle enthusiasts on this SE: I'd be really really grateful if you could tell me some book or website or resource, etc. that contains predominantly **the same type of puzzles** as the two examples I gave above. In case you're aware. (I don't know what these types of puzzles are called - but I notice they kind of rely on wordplay to make the listener make assumptions or imagine a scenario, and then the answer goes against those standard assumptions/prejudices/experience)

Comment: This is called [tag:lateral-thinking].

Comment: I would search using several of the following terms: 'brain teasers', 'trick questions', 'lateral thinking', 'thinking outside the box' and 'story problems'.

Comment: Here's another one for you: I have two coins in my pocket. They add up to 55 cents. One of them is not a 50-cent piece. What are the two coins?

Comment: @LannyStrack: I'm not very familiar with the coin denominations in US. Are they 1, 5, 25, 50 - that's it, right?

Comment: Oh, sorry. They are: 1, 5, 10, 25, 50.

Comment: @LannyStrack: So I'm kind of dim and haven't been able to quickly solve it. The assumption I'm making is that they're currency coins. If that's so, it seems impossible to add to 55 without one being 50. Is it possible they're different type of coins (non currency), or are both of them indeed one of 1,5,10,25,50?

Comment: Here's a hint: it's a TRICK QUESTION, like the others you mentioned. You have to not let your brain make false assumptions. Read it and try again.

Comment: @LannyStrack: Ahhh I get it now! What a moron I am :'( Should've seen that sooner and focused on the wording of the 3rd statement. In any case, thanks a lot! I now know what kind of questions to look for.

Comment: You are training your brain! You are welcome, and good luck on your search.

Comment: There are a number of books with "lateral thinking puzzles" or similar words in their titles.